# Obtener la precisión y escala de un numero en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Cordial saludo.
Quisiera saber si existe alguna función que me permita identificar la precisión y la escala de un numero.
Por ejemplo, en una tabla, en un campo particular tengo el numero -124.325. Lo que busco es que la función, me indique que el numero tiene una precisión de 6 y una escala de 3.
De esta forma deseo conocer la precisión y escala de todos los numero que se encuentran en dicho campo, con el fin de corregir un error que se me esta presentando, el cual es el error "arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric". De esta forma considero que lo podría corregir.

Gracias.

Comment: Según entiendo, la columna es tipo varchar y tiene números que quieres convertir. ¿Es eso correcto? ¿Estás consiente que teniendo la precisión máxima podrías no tener la máxima escala y si tratas de obtener las dos, es probable que no tengas la precisión adecuada?

Comment: Hola Luis, la columna que tengo es de tipo decimal. Mi interés es identificar la precisión y la escala de cada dato en esa columna.

Comment: Si la columna que tienes es de tipo decimal, todos los datos tienen la misma precision y escala.

Comment: Así es, tienes razón Luis. Realmente el campo lo calculo en una tabla temporal que pone por defecto los tipos de datos, es por ello que deseo agregar unos campos donde pueda identificar la escala y la precisión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te podría valer una función como esta, aunque puedes tener problemas con los decimales:

```
CREATE Function MDec(@par decimal(20, 9)) returns char(14) as
begin
    declare @o varchar(21), @p tinyint, @s tinyint
    set @o = reverse(ltrim(str(abs(@par), 20, 9)))
    while substring(@o, 1, 1) = '0'
        set @o = substring(@o, 2, len(@o)-1)
    select @p = len(@o)-1, @s = charindex('.', @o)-1
    return 'decimal(' + str(@p, 2) + ', ' + str(@s, 1) + ')'
end
```

Se trataría de buscar algo así como `select max(dbo.MDec(miCampo)) from miTabla` para averiguar el valor máximo de conversión.